# In Which Cases Is Better To Use Clojure?

Tags: lisp, clojure, scheme

I develop in Lisp and in Scheme, but I was reading about Clojure and then I want to know, in which cases is better to use it than using Lisp or Scheme? Thanks

Comment: lisp is very generic, both scheme and clojure are lisp

Comment: @cobbal - Where he says "lisp", I think it's pretty safe to understand Common Lisp.

Comment: As cobbal said, Lisp is a family of languages, not a single language. Common Lisp is Common Lisp. It's not /the/ Lisp, so please don't refer to CL as just 'Lisp'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Clojure runs on the JVM" means you get the whole cornucopia of Java libraries available. You can make pretty GUIs in Swing, use Apache's Web client or server code, connect a ready-built Sudoku solver... whatever you like.

Another big plus of Clojure is its very polished concurrency support, with about 3 different flavors. If you have a compute-intensive, parallelizable task, Clojure can make it easy. Well, easier.

Update: Another argument. Clojure is pretty strongly functional, so it's a plus if you want to force yourself to think and write functionally.

Comment: Than I can have all the power of the Java Libarys and develop in a generic Lisp?

Comment: Yep, that sums it up pretty nicely. Except the "generic". Clojure is its own Lisp flavor. For example, function arguments go in [ square ] brackets. And `car` and `cdr` are called `first` and `rest`.

Comment: You will have a small bit of adjusting to do to learn the changes. But Clojure is a rather "friendly" lisp. Believe it or not: ( Fewer parentheses! )

Comment: Thanks very much. I've write generic, because of Scheme that is a generic Lisp, then I just generalized all **;)**

Comment: Generic: "relating to or common to or descriptive of all members of a genus". Shoot me for being pedantic, but Scheme and CL are both distinct dialects of Lisp, variations on a common theme; I wouldn't say either can claim to be generic. I'm not great with Lisp genealogy, but it's possible that there is NO generic Lisp. Or maybe I'm just being too picky :)

Comment: Does Java have a built-in sudoku solver these days?  Because it's not like Common Lisp is lacking for Sudoku solvers (googling for "lisp sudoku" turns up 1,370,000 hits).  :-)

Comment: Not built-in. But there seem to be lots of 3rd party implementations. I'll see your 1.37M hits and raise to 2.45M in Java!

Comment: CAR and CDR are FIRST and REST in Scheme and Common Lisp, too.

Comment: Isn't part of the beauty of Lisps how expressive the language is? Couldn't you just define `car` and `cdr` to be `first` and `rest`?

Comment: I wouldn't call Swing GUIs pretty. And common lisp has bindings to GUI toolkits too (http://cliki.net/GUI), including Gtk, KDE, Cocoa, and even SWT.

Answer (score 55):

This question is impossible to answer.  You should use Clojure nearly 100% of the time over CL and Scheme, is what I would say.  But that doesn't mean you should listen to me.  Others can make a good argument that the opposite is the case.

For me, the syntax and function names in Clojure aesthetically pleasing.  Certain Java libraries are invaluable for what I do for data munging and web programming and GUI stuff.  Functional programming is challenging and enjoyable.  Clojure's flaws are unimportant and outweighed by its benefits in my eyes.  Certain intolerable flaws in other Lisps are "fixed" in Clojure, because it's new and it can ignore backwards compatibility.  It has a novel and arguably powerful approach to concurrency.  The Clojure community is vibrant and welcoming and awesome.  All of this says as much about me and what I value as it does about Clojure or other Lisps.

There are libraries for CL and Scheme that don't exist in Clojure or Java.  There are people who dislike how Clojure uses too much syntax like `[]` and `{}` and want to use parens everywhere.  If you want CLOS-style OOP or lots of mutable data structures, another Lisp is arguably better.  The JVM is heavyweight, maybe too heavyweight and too much baggage for some people.  A lot of Java leaks into Clojure (by design) and this offends some people's sensibilities.  The STM and immutable data structures have overheads that make certain things (e.g. number crunching) slower or less elegant.  Clojure is new and still rough in certain areas, still rapidly changing and evolving in others.  Clojure has yet to pass the test of time, whereas other Lisps already have.  Clojure is not a "standard" and some people find a language defined by an implementation to be unappealing.  And so on.  None of these things matter to me, but they may to you.

This is almost entirely subjective.  Which language you should use depends on what you already know, what you are willing to learn, what libraries you want to use, what editors and tools you're comfortable with, what language flaws you're willing to live with and work around and what flaws you can't tolerate, and what helps you get your work done faster, more cheaply, more enjoyably, or achieve whatever your goals are.

Basically, whatever makes you feel warm and fuzzy.  Learn them all and then make an informed choice based on your own tastes, and use whichever one you like the best.  They're all good.

Comment: For a question that's "impossible to answer", you did a pretty good job!

Comment: Tell that to the anonymous down-voters.  (Thanks, down-voters!)

Comment: There's room in the world for CL and Clojure both.  Honestly I think there's mutual respect for the most part from people in both communities, as it should be.

Comment: Indeed. But CL fanatics tend to be territorial, and that's where I imagine your down votes are coming from.

Comment: This is a great answer. I've been thinking about how to answer this myself and have similar feelings about the pros and cons of Clojure as you. Like you say "whatever makes you feel warm and fuzzy" ends up being the most important reason!

Comment: +1 for giving reasons *not* to use your favorite language.

Answer (score 8):

Clojure should be used when

- you need to work with existing java code.
- you work with people who are allergic to lisp ("boss, i would like to use a java concurrency library called clojue vs. I would like to re-write this in scheme" [1]
- you will be programming for a multi-processor system.

Scheme would be better when:

- you need to prove your code is correct. Clojures (call out to java) hinders but does not prevent this.
- you are working with people who are allergic to java.
- you are developing for a platform with no (new enough) JVM

[1] yes this is a bad bad bad reason. such is the world we live in...

Answer (score 8):

When? As much as possible.
Why? Immutable Data Structures - they really are that good. There are plenty of [other reasons](http://clojure.org/features) too.

Answer (score 8):

[ABCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) (Armed Bear Common Lisp) and a several of Scheme implementations (KAWA, SISC, ...) are also running on the JVM.

Generally Common Lisp is available in different 'flavors' - ABCL is one of them. Other compile to C, to native code, have extensive development environments or specialized extensions like logic languages or databases.

Clojure OTOH is a new Lisp dialect with emphasis on lazy functional programming and concurrent programming. Its author (Rich Hickey) is a very experienced software developer (he has also written Java and .net interfaces for Common Lisp) and did an excellent job with Clojure. Even though there is some hype around the language, it is worth checking out - it is definitely one of the better Lisp dialects developed in recent years (compared to say Newlisp or Arc).

Comment: Armed Bear Common Lisp? Really? You're not just pulling our legs? Yep, them Lispers are crazy.

Comment: 'The right of the people to keep and arm bears shall not be infringed!'

Comment: I find that Stoned Bear Common Lisp is a better implementation, generally less violent and more relaxed than ABCL.

Answer (score 8):

There are lot's of reasons, some mentioned above. My take is:

1. The pre-existing libraries. This is *such* a benefit. I just can't praise this feature enough.
2. The language is more adapted to the
   hardware currently available
   (multi-core) and the development
   paradigms in use today. It is so much easier to reason about concurrency. The functional aspects are nicer too. You can do functional programming in Lisp, obviously, but it is very easy to break the paradigm unknowingly, unwittingly, and unintentionally.
3. Cross platform. I run identical
   programs on Linux, Windows, and the
   Mac. There are lot's of native Lisps
   that run across platforms, but
   support for all features on all
   platforms is a bit spotty and you
   constantly have to be on the alert
   for things that are missing on one
   platform or the other. Likewise,the
   libraries you need are not always
   consistently supported across
   platforms. ABCL and some of the
   JVM Scheme implementations have this
   consistent support as well, but I
   still prefer Clojure because of
   point 2.
4. The nature of the language
   community. Let's face it, a lot of
   the time the Common Lisp community
   is just nasty to deal with. That is
   not the case with Clojure at all.
   It's easy to get useful help without
   the condescension and meanness that
   often comes with an answer from the
   Common Lisp community. As I have
   learned for myself several times,
   there is no question so stupid that
   you won't get a polite and helpful
   reply from the Clojure community.

If I had to find one thing to complain about, it would be IDE support. Maybe it's a question of learning new habits, but it is still easier for me to handle the mechanics of Java development than Clojure. I have tried, and use, Clojure Box, enclojure on NetBeas, La Clojure on Intellij IDEA, and Counterclockwise on Eclipse. They all work fine if you are working primarily from the REPL, but for compilation and execution of class files, they all still feel a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 7):

A subset of Clojure can also compile to **javascript**

Comment: So like all great forces, Clojure can be used for good but also for evil :)

Comment: From Brendan Eich's blog: "I was recruited to Netscape with the promise of "doing Scheme" in the browser." ... so Javascript is like, the ugly child in the LISP family?

Comment: Which probably makes JavaScript the most subversive of functional languages, teaching our kids functional programming right under our object oriented eyes!

Answer (score 3):

Clojure runs on the JVM (and on the CLR), so there is that.

Comment: Scheme and Common Lisp also run on the JVM.

Comment: Yeah, but Clojure is /built/ for the JVM, from the very beginning. It isn't just a half-cracked JVM implementation.

Comment: ABCL has been built for the JVM, too - from the very beginning. For the J editor. Originally started to be a scripting language for the J editor.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure's design is concerned with accommodating several styles of concurrent programming safely, deliberately making it difficult to mistakenly write the dangerous, rickety, and often broken concurrency-tolerant code in other languages. If your problem domain involves concurrent programming, Clojure's array of integrated tools for managing concurrency may be a better fit than the implementation-specific or lowest-common-denominator libraries available in other Lisps and Schemes.

Answer (score 3):

One of the greatest things about Clojure is the plethora of libraries you can use with it. You have the power of Java with the expressiveness of Lisp, and that is a badass combination. Clojure is more suited for real world development, because it was made for real world development. With Clojure, you have awesome libraries, awesome modern features, and an amazing community of helpful, like-minded people.

I would have to say that Clojure is a better language, all the way around. That is a highly argumentative statement to make, so I will point out here that this is just my honest opinion.

Clojure rocks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm always trying to learn new languages, so I'm interested in learning Clojure. But, aren't SBCL and some other Common Lisp implementations much, much faster than Clojure? Wouldn't you need considerably more than 4 processors (and a reasonably parallelizable task) to make up for the performance difference between a Clojure app and even a single-threaded SBCL version of the same app?

Comment: From my personal experience, I'd say it's a misconception that Clojure should be systematically slower than [brand X]. I've been writing number-crunching stuff in it for Project Euler and, given similar algorithms my Clojure code performs on par with my carefully and (dare I say) expertly hand-tuned Java code, same machine, which is almost as fast as C as long as I stay away from lots of unnecessary object creation. If you need stronger evidence please let me know what you have in mind and I'll try. Have Linux and gcc, will benchmark :)

Comment: And before you ask: I looked but was unable to find meaningful Clojure benchmarks. A few people posted some pretty random-looking stuff that gave me the impression they know much less about benchmarking than I do. So you can either accept my personal impression (though I was running puzzles, not benchmarking) -or- tell me what you'd like to see benchmarked (I'll post code and times) -or- do your own.

Comment: The [Computer language benchmarks game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org) includes comparison of Clojure and SBCL on several small programs.  Who wins?  SBCL on some programs, Clojure on others.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, I tend to favor Clojure over other languages in cases where either of these fit the bill:
(1). The domain model tends to look very recursive and/or graph-like.
(2). There's an opportunity to leverage a multi-core JVM environment (e.g., Elastic Beanstalk) 
(3). There's a fuzzy barrier between data and code (think RPN calculator where nodes can be operators or numbers)

These might sound a bit contrived, but a lot of my work involves dealing with graphs and trees of information, whether it's looking at social networks, some kind of constrained-based optimization, or semantic relationship building. I find that my other favorite language, Ruby, cannot give me the mix of expressiveness and raw computing power compared to Clojure, particularly when it comes to quantitative, recursive, concurrent-type problem solving.